# How to remove space from tuple inside a list output?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have this input  `P (0, 2,+1) (2, 0, -1) (0, 4,+1) (4, 0, -1)`  and I would like to have it printed out this way  `[(0, 2, 1), (2, 0, -1), (0, 4, 1), (4, 0, -1)]` 
. However, due to the extra space in the input I ran into this error. Without making any change to the input, I wonder if anyone could advise? Thanks

```
   algorithm_type_2 = list(eval(user_input_2))
 File "<string>", line 1
   (0,,2,+1),(2,,0,,-1),(0,,4,+1),(4,,0,,-1)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
user_input = input().split()
# input_list = user_input.split()
# algorithm_type = 'X'
algorithm_type = user_input.pop(0)

user_input_2 = ','.join(user_input)
algorithm_type_2 = list(eval(user_input_2))
print(user_input_2)
print(algorithm_type_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the context etc.. I know this is ugly, but in situations like this you can add a split character just to have a nice easy character to split on. Did I say split?

Here is what I did. Replace the closing bracket with a closing bracket and a "$" then split on the "$".

```
user_input = input().replace(")",")$").split("$")
# input_list = user_input.split()
# algorithm_type = 'X'
algorithm_type = user_input.pop(0)

user_input_2 = ','.join(user_input)
algorithm_type_2 = list(eval(user_input_2))
print(user_input_2)
print(algorithm_type_2)
```

This gave me the output you wanted.

```
= RESTART: C:/Users/Jeremy Wright/Desktop/Desktop Mess/Not Work/StackOverflow Stuff/example.py
(0, 2,+1) (2, 0, -1) (0, 4,+1) (4, 0, -1)
 (2, 0, -1), (0, 4,+1), (4, 0, -1),
[(2, 0, -1), (0, 4, 1), (4, 0, -1)]
>>>
```